# It had cost... and it cost

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

This is a standalone sentence taken from my exercise book:

> She bought her first watch at the age of eight. It **had cost** two
> pounds.

I wonder why they chose this sentence as an example. If those are events in chronological order, I usually see the events are merged in one sentence rather than separating them with a period [ . ]. This sentence appears in the exercise section of the unit that discusses past tenses. I also wonder, is it possible to use past simple like this?:

> She bought her first watch at the age of eight. It **cost** two
> pounds.

Comment: The use of "had" emphasizes *at that time in the past* it cost two pounds. You're alternative would be closer to the original intent as, "It cost two pounds, then".

Comment: It is very much a stylistic choice whether to merge two or more facts into a single sentence. It also depends on whether a writer wants to show a relationship between the two facts. Using "had cost" instead of "cost" seems odd to me too, and I prefer your suggestion.